# Android bottom line like kitkat in lolypop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In android kitkat the look and feel of an inputtext is something like ________/ (the border lines) but in lolipop is a line ________________

Is any wat to force the look and fell like in kitkat version

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you use standard Android GUI I guess it is not possible, moreover there is Android style guide describing you should follow common patterns in sake of consistency and better user experience. However I believe you can design your unique GUI from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) for forcing look like kitkat.

[image]